# Firebase Authentication com o googleAuth

Tags: javascript, firebase

aqui esta o codigo que estou usando para realizar o login, a conta do firebase esta configurada para receber o login

function signIn() {
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
}

o popup chega abrir, mas quando vc seleciona uma conta, aparece o erro

Erro 403: restricted_client Este aplicativo ainda não está configurado para fazer solicitações OAuth. Para fazer isso, configure a tela de consentimento do OAuth do aplicativo no Google Cloud Console.

mas eu vi alguns exemplos no youtube aonde não precisa fazer nenhuma configuração no Google Cloud Console, não estou entendendo o porque esta dando errado

Answer (score 0):

É necessário habilitar no Console do Firebase o método de login utilizando o Google, caso contrário Firebase irá recusar a autenticação.

Para habilitar, basta fazer o seguinte:
Console Firebase -> Authentication -> Métodos de login

Após chegar aí, basta habilitar o Google.